Sequences over groups and multiplicative recurrences
Feedback shift registers (FSRs) with nonlinear feedback function produce recurring sequences which satisfy polynomial recurrence relations defined by the feedback function. If the register cells are built for storing elements of a group and produces sequences over the group then the only feedback function possible is by defining words using the group operation. For instance recurrence such as
$$
g_{m+j}=\prod_{i=0}^{(m-1)}(g_{i+j})^{a_i}, j=0,1,2,...
$$
where $a_i$ belongs to $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ where $n$ is the order of the group for an FSR of length $m$. The complexity of the sequence can be considered as the shortest length of such FSR. What are previously known results on recurrences over groups? I shall highly appreciate if anyone can direct me to previous works on this kind of recurrence relations over groups, complexity of sequences under such recurrences etc.

This seems to be a generalization of binary LFSR theory, using "a group" rather than the Boolean field. I'm not familiar with that. Are you sure about "group"? Don't you need at least a ring, perhaps a field?

Yes such a FSR can be defined over a group. Does not require additional operation of a ring. The group operation itself defines the feedback rule.

Ah, thinking about it, yes. In a standard binary LFSR there is only XOR involved on the LFSR state bits (the addition operation of the Boolean field), thus we only need a group for the state values.
